# Naturally occurring examples of categories where composition depends on objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list

In the comments and answer to another recent [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422023/92164), it became apparent that category theorists who work with the ‘many hom-class’ definition of a category implicitly view composition as a function of five variables, three of them the objects that define the hom-classes the composable arrows live in.

This is, to put it mildly, very counterintuitive to me. I can’t think of a single time in my years working with (fibered) categories where composition depended on the objects involved, but maybe I just didn’t notice due to not looking for it. To this end,

> What are some examples of ‘naturally occurring’ categories $\mathcal{C}$ where we have objects $X,Y,Z,X’,Y’,Z’$ and arrows $$f\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)\cap {\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(Y’,Z’),$$ $$g\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\cap{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X’,Y’)$$ such that $$f\circ_{_{XYZ}}g\neq f\circ_{_{X’Y’Z’}}g?$$

Any relevant input is appreciated.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I post this Kleisli categories pop to mind — their characterization where we keep the same objects but change the composition seems to depend on objects, so maybe there is a naturally occurring Kleisli category for a monad on a category with overlapping hom-classes satisfying this property…

Comment: Most category theorists would regard this question as meaningless in general because the existence of such $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $X'$, $Y'$, $Z'$, $f$, $g$ is not an isomorphism-invariant property of the category $C$.

Comment: The key point is that the action of a functor (or in particular, an isomorphism of categories) on morphisms is also of "typed" nature, i.e., depends implicitly on the objects involved. If we allow in our foundations/definitions the possibility that $f : X \to Y$ and also $f : X' \to Y'$, we **definitely do not** require that $F_{XY}(f) = F(f) : FX \to FY$ and $F_{X'Y'}(f) = F(f) : FX' \to FY'$ are also equal! I wrote a longer answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418804/category-with-domain-codomain-relations/.

Comment: I like this question, and it’s quite hard to find a really unassailable example.  (Brian Shin’s answer is nice, but it would be even nicer to have an example that was not “hand-rolled” but constructed by standard textbook constructions.)  But the same phenomenon can be illustrated easily more with *functors* — it’s not hard to give examples where the action on morphisms really depends on their source and target. [cont’d in next comment]

Comment: [cont’d] E.g. take $\newcommand{\Set}{\mathrm{Set}}\Set$ to be the cat of sets, with hom-sets not artificially disjointified, i.e. morphisms are just functions $f$, not triples $(X,Y,f)$.  In particular, all morphisms out of the empty set are equal.  Now consider the functor $F : \Set \to \Set$ sending $X$ to $2^{0^X}$, so $F0$ has 2 elements, and $FX$ is a singleton for $X$ non-empty.  Now $F$ sends the empty function $0\to 0$ to the identity on the 2-element set $F0$; but it sends the empty function $0 \to 1$ to the unique (and non-injective) map $F0 \to F1$.

Comment: +1 for "hand-rolled"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to see that [Brian Shin’s example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/422314/2273) can be obtained from (standard many-hom-sets presentations of) more general constructions — so this shows clearly that constructions from the standard literature can lead to cases where composition genuinely depends on the objects.

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}$First, take the [**category of elements**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements) $\int_{\C^\op} F$ of a presheaf $F : \C^\op \to \mathrm{Set}$ to have:

- objects are pairs $(c,x)$, where $c \in \C$, $x \in F(c)$;
- maps $(c',x') \to (c,x)$ are maps $f : c' \to c$ such that $x|_f = x'$.

In particular, applying this over the terminal category $\C = \{*\}$ yields a construction of *discrete* categories $DX = \int_1 X$ in which all identities are equal: $DX((*,x),(*,x)) = \{ \id_*\}$.

Now, take the [**Grothenedieck construction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_construction) of a functor $\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}\D : \C \to \mathrm{Cat}$ to have:

- objects are pairs $(c,d)$, where $c \in \C$, $d \in \D(c)$;
- maps $(c,d) \to (c',d')$ are pairs $(f,g)$, where $f : c' \to c$, and $g : \D(f)(d) \to d'$.

Now take $G$ and $G'$ to be two different groups on the same underlying set, viewed as one-object categories; and consider the functor $\mathcal{G} : D2 \to \mathrm{Cat}$ picking out $G$ and $G'$.  Then the Grothendieck construction of $\mathcal{G}$ recovers Brian Shin’s example: its hom-sets are $\{\id_*\} \times  G$ and $\{\id_*\} \times G'$, i.e. the same set with different composition operations.

---

That said, let me address where you write:

> it became apparent that category theorists who work with the ‘many hom-class’ definition of a category implicitly view composition as a function of five variables […] This is, to put it mildly, very counterintuitive to me.

I really want to convince you it *shouldn’t* be counterintuitive: it’s just being slightly more explicit about something you’re doing all the time anyway, in many situations.

As in my [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/422068/2273), think about group operations (I’ll write multiplicatively).  We think of multiplication as a function of two variables — and for a fixed group, of course, it is.  But with varying groups, it also depends on the group.  And this really matters — for instance, when we take the product of a family of groups $\prod_i G_i$, we define its pointwise multiplication as $(x \cdot y)_i = x_i \cdot y_i$.  Formally of course this must mean $x_i \cdot_i y_i$ — the multiplication used depends on $i$. But this doesn’t disrupt our intuition of it as a binary operation; it just *also* depends on another parameter *i*.

Of course, you could avoid that dependence by assuming that the groups in the family must be disjoint, or compatible where they intersect, in order to form the product.  But I think most modern algebraists would find such a restriction highly artificial, and unnecessary anyway — the dependence is nothing to be worried by.  Indeed, once you look for it, this sort of thing is *everywhere* in mathematical practice.  A large part of Martin-Löf’s original motivation for dependent type theory was analysing how mathematicians use this sort of dependency in practice.  For me, meeting dependent type theory was like [Molière’s character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bourgeois_gentilhomme) learning he’d been speaking prose all his life.

Coming back to the typed-hom-sets definition of category: The point isn’t to *focus* on the extra dependence on objects.  The point is to let us *ignore* the question intersection/disjointness of objects, and view it as just as irrelevant as the question of whether different abstract groups are disjoint; and we achieve it by exactly the same mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

How about the following. Define a category $\mathcal{C}$ with two objects $A,M$ and the following hom-sets.

1. $\mathrm{Hom}(A,A) = \mathrm{Hom}(M,M) = \mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers (including zero), and
2. $\mathrm{Hom}(A,M) = \mathrm{Hom}(M,A) = \varnothing$.

The composition is specified by

1. $\mathrm{Hom}(A,A) \times \mathrm{Hom}(A,A) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,A)$ is addition $(n,m) \mapsto m+n$, and
2. $\mathrm{Hom}(M,M) \times \mathrm{Hom}(M,M) \to \mathrm{Hom}(M,M)$ is multiplication $(n,m) \mapsto mn$.

Is this "naturally occurring"? Maybe not.

Comment: Ah, I guess this is exactly what @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine was talking about in the linked post, just packaged as an example.

Comment: This is interesting; I would call this class of examples “totally disconnected”, where we basically just take a bunch of monoid structures on the same set and form a category with an object for every monoid and define composition in the hom-class for each object to be the corresponding monoid operation. Are there any examples with ${\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\neq\emptyset$ for some $X\neq Y\in\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: The example is natural, and even more so if we replace $\mathbb{N}$ with a group $G$. The we have a groupoid consisting of two copies of $G$ qua category. For instance, this could appear as an exercise for students: show that a group $G$ qua a category is equivalent to the groupoid consisting of two copies of $G$.

Comment: @AlecRhea we could do something a bit contrived and just add a third object to the above example which is final.

Comment: @BrianShin Nice! And I agree with Andrej, this would make a great introductory exercise — if the books I learned from had an exercise along these lines it would have avoided the semi-existential crisis I’ve been having about disjoint hom-sets for the past few weeks.